# SQL Select and separate duplicates from single records from a JDBC ResultSet

Tags: sql, select, jdbc, duplicates, resultset

I currently have the following query

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2  
FROM   table1     
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1=table2.col6  
WHERE  col3 IN 
           (SELECT col1 
            FROM table3 
            WHERE col4 IN (
                   SELECT col4 
                   FROM table4 
                   WHERE col5 LIKE '%XYZ%'
               )       
            )  ORDER BY table1.col1
```

The Result I get is as follows

```
COL1  |  COL2
Bob      LA
BOB      NY
Charlie  SF
Donald   Phoenix
Edward   Chicago
Edward   DC
Florence Miami
George   Sunnyvale
Helen    Orlando
Helen    Houston
```

If you observe the results, the following entries are duplicated on Col1 (Bob, Edward, Helen). The following are only single records(Charlie, Donald, Florence, George).

What I want are 2 different queries where  one query should return only the single records and another query should return only the duplicates. "I need BOTH Col1 and Col2 returned from both the queries". I have tried to modify, but either it gives an error or it does not result in any  reults .

Desired result

Query1 result (Only single records)

```
COL1  |  COL2
Charlie  SF
Donald   Phoenix
Florence Miami
George   Sunnyvale
```

Query2 result (Only duplicate  records returned)

```
COL1  |  COL2
Bob      LA
BOB      NY
Edward   Chicago
Edward   DC
Helen    Orlando
Helen    Houston
```

Comment: where is the col3 coming from?

Comment: can u post some sample data n desired o/p

Comment: What DBMS are you using?? Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL? something else?  The answer for this varies depending on the DBMS (and which version too)...

Comment: @appclay DB/ver is Oracle 10g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And if it isn't Oracle, get familiar with the `GROUP BY xxx HAVING yyy = z` construct.

Simply adding it to your query won't work because you want to select also a column you are not grouping by, but here is one simple way of eating your cake and having it:

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2  
FROM   table1     
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1=table2.col6  
WHERE  col3 IN 
       (SELECT col1 
        FROM table3 
        WHERE col4 IN (
               SELECT col4 
               FROM table4 
               WHERE col5 LIKE '%XYZ%'
           )       
        )
AND col1 IN (
    SELECT table1.col1
    FROM   table1     
        INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1=table2.col6  
    WHERE  col3 IN 
       (SELECT col1 
        FROM table3 
        WHERE col4 IN (
               SELECT col4 
               FROM table4 
               WHERE col5 LIKE '%XYZ%'
           )       
        )
    GROUP BY table1.col1
    HAVING COUNT(table1.col1) > 1
)
ORDER BY table1.col1
```

Comment: Just about to post the same, however, I wasn't sure about the sub query craziness going on there. The cols need their table prefix, table1.col1. This should probably just be included as part of the initial Join and not a subselect.

Comment: @Jason - You are right.  I edited the answer to fix the SQL syntax.  Moved ORDER BY to the end, and added the missing qualifiers you mention.  Honestly I also have no idea what is exactly the underlying schema, but this (anti)pattern works correctly with about anything.

Comment: The HAVING COUNT would be either =1 or >1 depending on whether I need a single record or a duplicate. This query worked very well. Thanks Jirka

Answer (score 0):

With oracle, analytic functions are your friend.  If you don't mind having an extra column in your data you can do something like this:

For single results:

```
SELECT 
      table1.col1,
      table2.col2,  
      count(*) over(partition by table1.col1) AS col1count
FROM   table1     
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1=table2.col6  
WHERE  col3 IN 
       (SELECT col1 
        FROM table3 
        WHERE col4 IN (
               SELECT col4 
               FROM table4 
               WHERE col5 LIKE '%XYZ%'
           )       
        )  ORDER BY table1.col1 
     AND col1count = 1
```

and for the duplicates just change the last line to

```
     AND col1count > 1
```

Comment: thanks....but I get this error "ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected" . I assume the col1count on lines 4 and the last line are actually col1 COUNT. But that did not work either and I got "ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended . I assume its a minor syntax issue.

Comment: Thanks..but there are still some syntax issues .